# rails loading select options via ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, select

I have a question regarding loading data to a select form_helper in Rails via Ajax request.

Right now, I have a select input field that loads about 8000 products in it in a form (grouped by users)

Because of this, it take about 16 seconds for the full http request to complete and the page to load.  It'd like for the page to load, and then options in my select input field to load the records via ajax so the page it's stuck loading until all products are loaded.

Here's my select input field:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:original_serial_number, 
      @users, 
      :products,
      :display_name, 
      :serial_number, 
      :asset_tag_and_serial_number_and_model, include_blank: true) %>
```

Any hints on how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you use pagination and infinite scrolling. You will find several articles with tutorials. One, for instance: http://christianvarga.com/simple-infinite-scroll-with-rails-and-jquery/ . Your action should be an ajax target.

Answer (score 7):

To load select records via ajax, I suggest you do it by json request.

So, in your view you send a trigged request passing an id:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#trigger_select').change(function() {
          $.ajax({
             url: "<%= remote_select_url %>", // this will be routed
             type: 'GET',
             data: {
               send_id: $("#yourIdContainer").val()
             },
             async: true,
             dataType: "json",
             error: function(XMLHttpRequest, errorTextStatus, error){
                        alert("Failed: "+ errorTextStatus+" ;"+error);
                    },
             success: function(data){
                // here we iterate the json result
                for(var i in data)
                {
                  var id = data[i].id;
                  var title = data[i].title;
                  $("#subject_select").append(new Option(title, id));
                }        

             }
           });
        });
      });
  </script>
```

Then, you must route your remote_select action on routes.rb

```
  get 'controller/action', :as => 'remote_select'
```

Your controller:

```
  def action
    #filter using id passed by ajax
    @your_model = Your_model.apply_your_filter(params[:send_id]) 
    render json: @your_model
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask for hints, here is an idea, I don't know of any JS event that can detect the position inside a select field, so what you could do is  a simple ajax pagination.

You could set the default page value in a hidden field to 1 like

`<%= f.hidden, id: "page", value: 1 %>`, and let the select field have a "More" option, which you can put in the  tag or as link beside the select field.

Then have a jquery saying

```
$.getJSON("/action/$('#page').val()", function(data) {
    //remove and re render the options 
    $.each(data, function(){
        $("#select_id").append('<option value="'+ this.value +'">'+ this.name +'</option>')
    )
})
```

and bind the above to a "click" function to the  or the  dom.
and on `ajaxSuccess` change the value of the hidden field to +1.
and it would be nice to send the data in json.